# Unable to add tag to instance python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm creating an ec2 instance in python boto3 with this code:

```
image_id = input("Enter the image id: ")
max_count = input("Enter the number of instances you want: ")
instance_type = input("Enter the instance type: ")
key_name = input("Enter the key name you want to use: ")
name_tag = input("Enter the host name: ")
instance = ec2_resource.create_instances(
    ImageId=image_id,
    MinCount=1,
    MaxCount=max_count,
    InstanceType=instance_type,
    KeyName=key_name
)
```

But when I try to apply a name tag with this code:

```
instance.add_tag('Name', name_tag)
```

I get an error that says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\aws_create_ec2_simple.py", line 134, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\aws_create_ec2_simple.py", line 130, in main
    create_instances()
  File ".\aws_create_ec2_simple.py", line 125, in create_instances
    instance.add_tag('Name', name_tag)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'add_tag'
```

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: create_instances() seems to return a list, not a single instance. so your error message says "'list' object has no attribute 'add_tag'" because it really doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boto3 [Instance](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#instance) class does not have an `add_tags()` method.

You should use [create_tags()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.create_tags). For example:

```
instances = ec2_resource.create_instances(
    ImageId=image_id,
    MinCount=1,
    MaxCount=max_count,
    InstanceType=instance_type,
    KeyName=key_name
)

for instance in instances:
    tag = instance.create_tags(
        Tags=[
            {
                'Key': 'Environment',
                'Value': 'QA'
            },
            {
                'Key': 'Owner',
                'Value': 'Jason'
            }
        ]
    )
```

Also, note that [create_instances()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.create_instances) returns a list of instances, not a single instance.